# laravel public/index.php - Whoops, looks like something went wrong

Tags: laravel

i just installed Laravel (throught composer):

```
OS - Windows 8;
Local Server - Open Server;
```

When i go to "tlaravel.loc/"i get the core folder with all directories:
[image: Image with core directory]

If i go to http://tlaravel.loc/**public**/
i get 500 error and: Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

After modify rights (maked writable) for next directories:
- public
- bootstrap/cache
- storage
i resolved the problem with 500 eror, but on the page is still the error:
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

Comment: You should run command in your terminal for composer update:-

composer update

Comment: hi, thanks for anwewer, after composer update, the problem still remains

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now you've need to run these commands:-

For generate env key-

```
php artisan key:generate
```

And after that

```
composer update
```

It'll resolve yours issue.

Comment: Hi @Rk verma, i maked the recomended steps, but the problem still remains

Comment: Whats the exact issue, Can you please screen screenshot?

Comment: Did you created .env file?

Comment: Yes,
Please rename .env.example to .env
If your OS not allowing to do this, just try with your editor like phpstorm.

Comment: Because .env file responsable for connectivity, Please rename that and try.

Answer (score 3):

The Upper answer is totally right, I'll explain it better what do you have to do in order to fix this problem

In your laravel project that you've installed, you have all of these folders and files in the root directory, as you can see... there's an `.env.example` file in the root folder

WINDOWS... maybe other OS **DOES NOT** understand/recognize what the heck is that for, but they need an enviroment file in the root folder in order to get the key that allows us to open the local server.

so what we have to do is to rename that file `.env.example` to just `.env`.

after that you have to try again putting in the shell/terminal:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

and then....

```
composer update
```

after that you run your server again and it will work!!!!